# How to get selected options from two different <select> elements with .val()

Tags: jquery, select

So I have two basic select dropdowns with some options:

```
<div id="form">    

   <select name="firstselect">
     <option>English</option>
     <option>French</option>
   </select>

   <select name="secondselect">
     <option>Girls</option>
     <option>Boys</option>
   </select>

</div>

<div id="print_html_here"></div>
```

I would like to be able to use .val() to grab BOTH of the user's choices and then print some html (depending on what combination of choices was made) into the last div.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    $("#form").on('change', function(e) {

    var selectedValue = $('select[name=firstselect]', 'select[name=secondselect]').val();

    if (selectedValues === "English" "Girls") {
           $("#print_html_here").html("You have selected English Girls.");
     }
    elseif (selectedValues === "French" "Girls") {
           $("#print_html_here").html("You have selected French Girls.");
     }

    });
```

But no joy. I think the syntax is wrong for when I am trying to val the two select elements. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `if (selectedValues === "English" "Girls") {` This isn't valid syntax, nor is `elseif`. Best to figure out what sort of variable you want to work with - were you trying to use an array?

Comment: You can only get the value of one element at a time. So using:

    `$('select[name=firstselect]', 'select[name=secondselect]').val()` 

will only return the value of the first matching selector in the collection

Comment: Okay so if I cannot use val() to get the values of two elements at the same time I must use an array? Could you guys help me with this as I've not used one before and wouldn't know how to implement it in the above situation.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few mistakes, some of they are:

**1)** First I suggest to add `ids` to your html elements, so they are more easy to target from `Jquery`.

**2)** The `change` event listener should be over the `selects`, not over the `form`.

**3)** You need to add `values` attributes to your options...

So, taking into consideration previous comments, I have reorganized your code like this:

```js
$("#sel1, #sel2").on('change', function(e)
{
    var firstSel = $('#sel1').val();
    var secondSel = $('#sel2').val();

    if (firstSel == 1 && secondSel == 1)
        $("#print_html_here").html("You have selected English Girls.");
    else if (firstSel == 2 && secondSel == 1)
        $("#print_html_here").html("You have selected French Girls.");
    else if (firstSel == 1 && secondSel == 2)
        $("#print_html_here").html("You have selected English Boys.");
    else if (firstSel == 2 && secondSel == 2)
        $("#print_html_here").html("You have selected French Boys.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="form">    

   <select id="sel1" name="firstselect">
     <option value="1">English</option>
     <option value="2">French</option>
   </select>

   <select id="sel2" name="secondselect">
     <option value="1">Girls</option>
     <option value="2">Boys</option>
   </select>

</div>

<div id="print_html_here"></div>
```